# .NET Compact Framework application installation creator

Tags: installation, compact-framework

Is there tool to create installation programs (as InnoSetup) for .NET Compact Framework applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an article on MSDN entitled '[Deploying .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Applications with .cab and .msi Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx)' that covers both CAB and MSI creation.

Answer (score 1):

I use CAB Manager.  It is a great tool for creating and editing CABs.

http://www.ocpsoftware.com/products.php

Comment: is there alternative for free?

Comment: It's not free, but it is worth the $60 if you work with Compact Framework routinely.

Comment: I found also free alternative for it: http://freewareppc.com/utilities/msceinf.shtml